How to prevent or easily fix off-screen items when connecting via Chrome Remote Desktop and resizing the screen?
My Windows host computer is running 4K resolution normally, and when I use chrome remote desktop I have it set to auto-resize, so it resizes the display to 1080p. When this happens, most apps are still usable, such as Google Chrome, Visual Studio, Unity etc. but a few apps such as Notepad and Windows Explorer will become invisible when I click on them due to being off screen. Is there some sort of setting to prevent this, or a hotkey to force them back onscreen?

@DrMoishePippik If you are suggesting I normally use it at 1080p even when not chromoting, that is infeasible because I prefer to work in 4k at my desktop. If you are suggesting to manually change it to 1080p, how is that different from what chrome remote desktop "auto resize" is already doing?

Do any of these methods also work for Chrome Remote Desktop?
